# xl.Workbook() (pyvot) doesn't open an excel workbook

Tags: python, windows, excel

I would like to create an excel workbook with [pyvot](http://packages.python.org/Pyvot/tutorial.html) as in [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oi3QKuFugWk&hd=1) . 
Pyvot is installed correctly because I can import it without an error. But when I do:

```
import xl
xl.Workbook()
```

I  get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'workbook'
>>> xl.Workbook()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvot-0.1.2-py2.7.egg\xl\sheet.py", line 91, in     __init__
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 529, in EnsureDispatch
    disp = win32com.client.Dispatch(prog_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 108, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 85, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

I don't have Python tools for visual studio installed though.

1. Do I need Python tools for visual studio (PTVS) to work with pyvot?
2. Could lower versions of excel then excel 2010(e.g. excel 2007) work with pyvot?
3. Do I need to set anything up in excel to make it work with pyvot?

If the answer of one of the questions above did not explain why I couldn't make that code snippet work, what should I do to get it working correctly?

---

I have installed excel 2010. Pyvot is installed correctly because I don't get any errors when I do `import xl`. When I type the following in pywin32:

```
import xl
xl.Workbook()
```

I get this NameError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'xl' is not defined
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

From [Pyvot](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pyvot) homepage:

> Pyvot requires CPython 2.6 or 2.7 with the Python for Windows extensions (pywin32) installed, and Office 2010. If a clean Python session can import the win32com module, Pyvot is ready to be installed.

So from what it is described, no need of PTVS, Excel 2010 is required, and you need `win32com` module up and running in your current interpreter. I use this configuration without any issue.

Comment: I have installed excel 2010 now, but I still get a NameError (see updated original post), any clue why?

Comment: Are you sure your `import xl` statement is working fine ? your error is likely coming from `xl.Workbook()` when xl is unknown

Answer (score 1):

Happened same to me,  I just tried it today.
try: 
xl.workbooks()

which is consistent with the VBA code.